# Channel receive operator used with something which is not a channel?

Tags: go, syntax, channel

I would like to understand the meaning of this code:

`<-`

in the following snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func doSomething(s string) {
    fmt.Println("doing something", s)
}

func startPolling() {
    for {

        // Here:
        <-time.After(2 * time.Second)

        go doSomething("from polling")
    }
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello")
}

func main() {
    go startPolling()

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

While I understand what this code does (it prints *doing something from polling* every 2 seconds) I don't understand why `<-` is being used outside of its normal context of sending to/receiving from channels.

Put in other words, I don't see a channel here.

Comment: "Put in other words, I don't see a channel here." `time.After` returns a channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[time.After](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) returns a channel:

```
func After(d Duration) <-chan Time
```

The `<-time.After(...)` just waits until there is an element to read from the channel, which happens after the amount of time specified has elapsed. The channel value is the time after the duration.

This function is a package function, which should not be confused with the method on `Time`:
`func (t Time) After(u Time) bool` which just returns whether `t` is after `u`. This method would be called with: `if sometimevariable.After(...) {`

Comment: Thank you, I was getting confused with the following: `func (t Time) After(u Time) bool`

Comment: Good point. I've added a mention of the `Time.After` method for future visitors.